# How to use webpack/babel to preparse JS template strings?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Let's say for example, I want to create a `rot13` template tag. You could use it like this:

```
 let secret = rot13`This is a secret.`;
```

Now I could implement this tag in JavaScript, but I want to pre-parse it such that my compiled bundle would actually contain:

```
 let secret = "Guvf vf n frperg.";
```

How can I do this? Do I have to create a Babel plugin to hook into their parser? What would that look like?

Now what if I want Webpack to also spit out a file called `rotated_strings.txt` which contains a list of all these strings that have been transformed? How do I collect them up? i.e., how do I get Babel and Webpack to communicate such that Babel can do the inline transform but somehow notify Webpack to generate this extra file?

Comment: I don't think babel is capable of executing `rot13` for you, its purpose it to transpile from one thing to another. Take a look at the exponential transformer plugin, which will transpile `x ** y` into `Math.pow(x, y)`, it doesn't actually pre-compile: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator

Comment: @Xotic750 I know it's possible to do, one way or another. Apollo and Relay do this for `gql` and I think there's a couple that do it for `css` and such. Babel *can* transform template tags, I just want to put some special logic around a very specific tag.

Comment: Not massively robust, but here's a starting point to prove it can be done... https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/89a6bdce0165d2661385828d9d85a7e0/b3fd89050bf81d9b7734ff1a2b1c9dabb7b47aeb

Comment: In reality you'd obviously want to replace the entire literal with a string node, but I don't know Babel that well and I have a train to catch :p Hopefully you/someone else can get it the rest of the way there.

Comment: Ok, that's cool.

Comment: @JoeClay That's a great start. Thank you. Now I just have to figure out how   to push those results to webpack as well.

Comment: I think you'll have trouble getting the babel-loader to emit some kind of result from this kind of parsing. Have you thought about creating a custom loader that processes your JS files before the babel-loader? That way, you have more control as to what to do when you find rot13 in your code.

Comment: @NickWyman Well that's the part I'm having trouble figuring out. I'd happily create a new loader to do this, but in order to extract the template strings, I'd have to parse the JS. And I'd have to use the Babylon parser. But then everything would be parsed twice. Not sure if there's a way to avoid that.

Comment: You can definitely explore creating a babel plugin here. Get familiar with AST.

Comment: @AftabKhan Yeah, Joe gave me a great example to go on, but how do interact with Webpack from inside a Babel plugin?

Comment: @mpen You don't need to think too hard on that. You need to include that plugin in the Babel (`.babelrc`) that you are using on your `.js` files. I'm guessing you have a eslint & Babel loaders on all your js

Comment: @AftabKhan Including the plugin isn't a challenge. The problem is that the plugin can only transform code. How do I generate a brand new file as the result of combing all the files in my project? (last paragraph of my question)

Comment: Inside the visitor function for the string literals where you do the replacement. You could write into a file using `fs` apis, but it would be more frequent.

Comment: Or you can maintain a global array. Initialize it in the `program`-> `entry` visitor, and update the file in the `program` -> `exit` visitor. That would keep it more optimal that writing it every time you transform

Comment: Tagged templates are a headache in webpack... im here for 48hours straight now trying to solve how to get my tagged template string manipulation handler to work... but it just dosent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the following.
https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/89a6bdce0165d2661385828d9d85a7e0/4d745f3e8b5bfd25ba919cff567f27055d9e3a75

- I have built up on what Joe Clay had created in the comments.
- Right now this console logs all the things it has changed once at the end
- And in the comments I have written what you can replace it with once you move it to using in your project build env (assuming it to be Node)

PS: I have used the sync APIs in comments to quickly demonstrate it, you should probably switch over to Async APIs

**Update**: When you write this in Babel plugin, be sure to **not** set quasi and cooked attrs, but use `path.replaceWith(t.stringLiteral(cooked))` instead

Comment: That's pretty good, but I still want to hook into the [Webpack API](https://webpack.js.org/development/how-to-write-a-plugin/#example) and *emit* the extra file instead.

Comment: This [line](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/blob/master/src/index.js#L47) specifically tells me that it won't work. They invoke `babel-core` only with source string and options. So it doesn't have webpack context where this is done!

Comment: You need to write a loader, require `babel-core` yourself and run Babel.tranform with your plugin. Then you have the transformed code and also access to webpack's context.

Comment: If you can create a small setup where all of these are present. I'll try to show you what I am saying.

Comment: I think I've got it. Thanks for the tips. I'll come back to this after I get back from vacation :-)

Comment: Be sure to let me know how it went